# How to evalute $\lim_{a\to x}\left(\int a \mathrm{d}x\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

i have the following expression:

$\lim_{a\to x}\left(\int a  dx\right)$

But i don't know which way to evalute is the correct way. I found these two ways to do it:

$\lim_{a\to x}\left(\int a  \mathrm{d}x\right)=\lim_{a\to x}(ax+c)=x^2+c$

Or:

$\lim_{a\to x}\left(\int a  \mathrm{d}x\right)=\int x \mathrm{d}x=\frac {x^2}{2}+c$

Which one is correct?

Thank you

Comment: The expression is not well-defined, as $\int a dx$ is not a function but a class of functions.  Hence it is meaningless to take limits with it.  That said, pulling a limit into an integral, as in your second method, is not a valid technique without added assumptions.

Comment: You cannot swap integral with limit. The first option is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It equals $x^2+c$ Because limits cannot be placed inside an integral. They are not interchangeable in order.